# cv2/ffmpeg "grabFrame packet read max attempts exceeded" error after exactly reading certain number of frames

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I am using OpenCV to extract frames from videos, run a segmentation AI model, and save the frames and masks to a folder. When I run my code to extract the frame from  I encounter the error "grabFrame packet read max attempts exceeded" after processing a certain number of frames. This issue occurs consistently for the same videos across multiple environments.

Error message:

```
[ WARN:0@379.898] global cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1541 grabFrame packet read max attempts exceeded, if your video have multiple streams (video, audio) try to increase attempt limit by setting environment variable OPENCV_FFMPEG_READ_ATTEMPTS (current value is 10000)
```

Minimum Reproducible Example

```
import os
import cv2

videofilename = "test.mp4"
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(videofilename)
frameNum = 0

createfolder = os.getcwd() + '/' + videofilename.split(".")[0] + '/'
if not os.path.exists(createfolder):
    os.makedirs(createfolder)
    os.makedirs(createfolder + "/frames/")

while True:
    success, frame = capture.read()
    if success is False:
        break
    frameNum += 1
    framedownloadname = videofilename.split(".")[0] + '-fr' + str(frameNum) + '.jpg'
    framedownloadloc = createfolder + '/frames/' + framedownloadname
    print(framedownloadloc)
    cv2.imwrite(framedownloadloc, frame)
    img = cv2.imread(framedownloadloc)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

capture.release()
```

As suggested in error, I increased the OPENCV_FFMPEG_READ_ATTEMPTS env variable up to 10000. However, this seems to have little to no effect on the number of frames before the error appears.

Comment: You're missing `cv2.WaitKey(0)`.

Comment: I would like this program to work without user input, so I used `cv2.WaitKey(1)` and the program still errors out with the above message at the 60th frame.

Comment: I tested you code and it worked. Just one frame and stop. Btw, I got no issue problem.